# Solving an online problem without maximizing or minimizing an objective

Tags: online-algorithms

You have a budget $B$ and a satisfaction level $L$. An indivisible product is available for sell and you are interested in buying. The product is divided into $n$ parts. Part $i$ of the product has positive value $v_i$.

On day $i$, you get to know $v_i$ and you have to decide how much price $p_i\geq0$ you would pay for this part of the product.

After $j$ days, given the values $v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_j$ and the prices you paid $p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_j$ for each value, you know that you can reach a satisfaction level of $(1+v_1p_1)(1+v_2p_2)\cdots(1+v_jp_j)$.

Your objective is to buy the product after $n$ days while you reach the satisfaction level of $L$ and pay no more than $B$.

Comment: "indivisible product... divided into $n$ parts"?!

Comment: @Aryeh you can see it as $n$ products.

Comment: This question is fundamentally unanswerable without assuming some distribution on $v_i$ (or at least properties of that distribution). Any strategy agnostic to such a distribution will have an adversary choice of $v_i$ that causes it to fail.

Comment: @orlp Can you see any similarity between this problem and some known problem in the literature?

Comment: @zdm A very, very rough similar-ish problem is the secretary problem.

Comment: For n=2 there is a strategy.  Once you see v1, compute the minimum value of v2, say v2*, such that the problem (v1, v2*) is feasible.  Then choose p1 and p2 to be the values that work for (v1, v2*).  This suffices because the actual v2 will be at least v2*.  @orlp, can you prove your claim that any online strategy will fail on at least one input?  I'm not so sure.

Comment: Note, also, for intuition, that for the modified the problem where we replace each $1+v_ip_i$ by $\exp(v_i p_i)$, there is an online strategy: set $p_i=0$ for all $i$ except the first where $v_i\ge \ln(L)/B$, and set that one to $B$.  (If there is no such $i$, then the instance is not feasible, because $$\prod_i \exp(v_ip_i) = \exp(\sum_i v_i p_i) < \exp(\ln(L)/B \sum_i p_i) \le \exp(\ln(L)/B \cdot B) = L.)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@orlp's intuition is correct.

**lemma.** *No online algorithm solves the problem in the worst case.*

*Proof.*  Consider the following instance:

$$f(p) = (1+p_1)(1+p_2)(1+p_3) \ge 8 \text{ with } B=3.$$

This instance has just one solution (one $p$ that satisfies it), namely $p=(1,1,1)$.  So, given $B=3$ and $L=8$ and just the first factor $1+p_1$, the algorithm has to choose $p_1 = 1$.

But then the adversary instead continues by defining the following instance:

$$g(p) = (1+p_1)(1+ 1.49 p_2)(1+0\cdot p_3) \ge 8 \text{ with } B=3.$$

This instance is feasible (e.g. for $p_1=p_2=3/2$ we have $g(p)\approx 8.1$). However, the algorithm committed to $p_1 = 1$, so the residual problem it is faced with is now $2(1+1.49 p_2) \ge 8$ with $p_2 \le 2$.  Since $2(1+1.49\cdot 2) < 2\cdot 4 = 8$, this residual problem is not feasible.

So the online algorithm cannot guarantee a solution, even if it knows in advance that it will face just one of the two instances above. $~~~\Box$